# How to add rows in a specified worksheet of google sheet via API?

Tags: database, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am able to add rows in single worksheet of Google Sheets via API. But lets say there are 5 more Worksheets and i want to add row in the 5th Worksheet. I have the sheet id's and sheet name also. How to do that via API?  I am not able to find this in Google SHeet API Reference.

I am making custom HTTP Call on a platform which is like Zapier/Integromat.

Below is the endpoint URL  https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1I15WeCfwV6sZs99XG-vkQuRMOeIEWPhPjK4aldeGCIY/values/Sheet1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&includeValuesInResponse=true

Below is the requestbody
{
"range": "Sheet1",
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
"values": [
[
"first",
"second"
]
]
}

Comment: Can you provide your current script and/or request body?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `I am making custom HTTP Calls on an API Integration Platform.`, can you provide your current request body of `I am able to add rows in single worksheet of Google Sheets via API.`?

Comment: Hi, I am unable to add in the comments because of character limitation. Can you check the question description?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see your current situation. In your situation, it seems that you are using Method: spreadsheets.values.append. In this case, unfortunately, the values cannot be put into the sheet by using the sheet index. It is required to use the sheet name of the 5th sheet in your Spreadsheet. If you want to retrieve the sheet name of the 5th sheet from the index of the sheet, it is required to use [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). But, in this case, a script might be required to be used.

Comment: Hey, Lets assume i know the worksheet name and worksheet id, Where can i add worksheet name in request body?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted a modified endpoint and request body in an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

From `Lets assume i know the worksheet name and worksheet id, Where can i add worksheet name in request body?`, if you have already known the sheet name of 5th sheet, you can directly use the sheet name. When your endpoint and request body is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{sheetName}:append?includeValuesInResponse=true&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

- Please replace `{spreadsheetId}` and `{sheetName}` with your Spreadsheet ID and sheet name of 5th sheet.

#### Request body:

```json
{"values":[["first","second"]]}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)